# Invalid Replication Server Name (IP Address) SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a server in production (SQL Server 2012) that someone tried to set up replication (distributor), but they used an IP address instead of the name.

I can see that the installation must have failed as there is no replication DB's in the msdb database and other items that are normally created during the process are also missing. The actual server name is returned by `Select @@SERVERNAME` and it is an instance so it returns NAME\XXX.

I have tried to run `EXEC sp_dropdistributor;` but it generates the following error:

> The name '127.0.0.1.master.sys.sp_MSrepl_getdistributorinfo' is not a valid identifier.

(I have replaced the IP with localhost).

I suspect this is as a result of the IP needing to be surrounded by `[` & `]`.

How can I kill the distribution and start again?

Given it is a production server I am apprehensive about just fiddling.

The server name in *datasource, srvname* fields used by the procedure have the IP address set as the name.

There only seems to be 1 row in the catalog (master.dbo.sysservers) that has a server name (srvname) set to the IP address.

Comment: What do you get if you query the `[msdb].[dbo].[MSdistpublishers]` table?

Comment: ...and do you have a `127.0.0.1` in your `<instance> | Server Objects | Linked Servers` (navigation tree) in SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

This might not work in your case, but it did work in my case....

First check that nobody is in the `distribution` database with:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sdes WHERE sdes.database_id = DB_ID('distribution');
```

If you find (a) session(s) in the database, then kill them with:

```
KILL <session_id>;
```

Next drop the `distribution` database:

```
EXEC sp_dropdistributiondb @database = N'distribution';
```

Then deactivate the `distributor` with:

```
EXEC sp_dropdistributor;
```

If the above command fails run:

```
EXEC sp_dropdistributor  @ignore_distributor = 1, @no_checks = 1;
```

<sup>***Reference:** [sp_dropdistributiondb (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-dropdistributiondb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem I have is the sp_dropdistributor generates errors when run due to the name of the distributor. The install did not get as far as creating the DB or some of the stored proc's.

Comment: Even with the additional parameters?

Comment: Yes, the stored proc's for the remove don't run as the SERVERNAME.master.sys.sp_MSrepl_getdistributorinfo fails as I think it should have been [SERVERNAME].master.sys.sp_MSrepl_getdistributorinfo. I'm surprised that they didn't do this in the storage of the server name if it contained fullstops.

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation, it turned out that the invalid IP address-based server had been set up as a linked server and distribution set to true.

Using SMS I was able to set the distribution flag to false even though the server was not reachable. After this, I was able to configure distribution on the server.

I found this by going into linked servers and reviewing each server with the name of the IP address, I was able to isolate the invalid server and change the distribution setting on the advance panel.

You are asked to confirm that you want to make a change to a server that is unreachable.